# Sql Server: CASE Statement does unexpected behavior when comparing to NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, case-statement

**Given:**

The following Select statement:

```
select case NULL
       when NULL then 0
       else 1
       end
```

**Problem:**

I'm expecting this to return 0 but instead it returns 1. What gives?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, NULL is not something you should attempt to compare for equality, which is what a case statement does.  You can use "Is NULL" to test for it.  There is no expectation that `NULL != NULL` or that `NULL = NULL`.  It's an indeterminate, undefined value, not a hard constant.

-- To encompass questions in the comments --

If you need to retrieve a value when you may encounter a NULL column, try this instead:

```
Case
  When SomeColumn IS NULL
  Then 0
  Else 1
End
```

I believe that should work.  As far as your original post is concerned:

```
Select Case NULL
  When NULL then 0 // Checks for NULL = NULL
  else 1 // NULL = NULL is not true (technically, undefined), else happens
end
```

The trouble is that your Case select automatically attempts to use equality operations.  That simply doesn't work with NULL.

Comment: @Martin - That's correct.  You shouldn't use comparison operators for NULL.  `IS NULL` is the correct way. My `NULL != NULL` was a reference to trying to compare two columns that may contain NULL values.  They won't equal each other, even if they are both NULL.

Comment: @Martin - Sorry, As I re-read it I gathered what you were explaining.  You're right, neither comparison operator is right with NULL.  I've tried to clean up the answer a bit.

Comment: Ok, let me ask you this then: I came across this when I was comparing a column that had a null value which was doing the same thing. So why would `select case SomeColumn when NULL then 0 else 1 end` Or are you saying that the problem lies in the `when` clause and not the `select case`?

Comment: @DJTripleThreat - I've added a comment to your original version.  I think that should clarify things. HTH.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat there is a big difference between `CASE WHEN SomeColumn IS NULL` (checking if the column has been assigned `NULL`) and `CASE SomeColumn WHEN NULL` (checking if the column *is equal to * `NULL`). Use the former syntax for predictable results.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to add this as a comment to Aaron's answer, but it was getting too long, so I'll add it as another (part of the) answer.

The [`CASE` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) actually has two distinct modes, simple and searched.

From BOL:

> The CASE expression has two formats:
>
> - The simple CASE expression compares an expression to a set of simple expressions to determine the result.
> - The searched CASE expression evaluates a set of Boolean expressions to determine the result.

When the simple `CASE` (your example) does what it describes as **comparison** it does an **equality comparison** - i.e. `=`

This is clarified in the later documentation:

> The simple CASE expression operates by comparing the first expression
>   to the expression in each WHEN clause for equivalency. If these
>   expressions are equivalent, the expression in the THEN clause will be
>   returned.
>
> - Allows only an equality check.

Because `anything = NULL` is always false in ANSI SQL (and if you didn't know this, you need to read up on NULLs in SQL more generally, particularly also with the behavior in the other searched comparison - `WHERE x IN (a, b, c)`), you **cannot** use `NULL` in a simple case and have it ever be compared to a value, with a `NULL` either in the initial expression or in the list of expressions to be compared against.

If you want to check for `NULL`, you will have to use an `IF/ELSE` construct or the searched `CASE` with a full expression.

I agree that it's kind of unfortunate there is no version which supports an IS comparison to make it easier to write:

```
select case colname
   when IS NULL then 0
   else 1
end
```

Which would make writing certain long `CASE` statements easier:

```
select case colname
   when IS NULL then ''
   when 1 then 'a'
   when 2 then 'b'
   when 3 then 'c'
   when 4 then 'd'
   else 'z'
end
```

But that's just wishful thinking...

An option is to use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE`:

```
select case COALESCE(colname, 999999) -- 999999 is some value never used
   when 999999 then ''
   when 1 then 'a'
   when 2 then 'b'
   when 3 then 'c'
   when 4 then 'd'
   else 'z'
end
```

But it isn't always a great option.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers, you need to change the syntax for `CASE` slightly to do this:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN NULL IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
    END;
```

Using the value in your syntax implicitly uses an equals comparison. `NULL` is unknown, and so is `NULL = NULL`, so with your current code you will always get <strike>zero</strike> 1 (geez I did it too).

To get the behavior you want, you can use [SET ANSI_NULLS ON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048%28SQL.100%29.aspx); however note that this can change other code in ways you may not be able to predict, and the setting is deprecated - so it will stop working at all in a future version of SQL Server (see [this SQL Server 2008 doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28SQL.100%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the IS NULL operator.  Standard comparison operators do not work with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these MSDN articles about Null that may be useful:

- [IS [NOT] NULL (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx)
- [Null Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504.aspx)